# How to make a unit test with SignInManager in .NET 6: Method not found

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, mocking

Here is my test that I try to make it pass:

```
    private ComptesController _comptesController;
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private Mock<IOptions<APISettings>> _aPISettings;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _userManager = new MockUserManager();
        _signInManager = new MockSignInManager(_userManager, null, null, null, null, null);

        var roleStore = new Mock<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>>().Object;
        var roleValidators = new List<IRoleValidator<IdentityRole>>();
        var keyNormalizer = new UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer();
        var errors = new IdentityErrorDescriber();
        var logger = new Mock<ILogger<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>>().Object;

        _roleManager = new MockRoleManager(roleStore, roleValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, logger);

        _aPISettings = new Mock<IOptions<APISettings>>();
        _aPISettings.Setup(a => a.Value).Returns(new APISettings());
        var identityResult = new Mock<IdentityResult>();

        _comptesController = new ComptesController(
            _signInManager,
            _userManager,
            _roleManager,
            _aPISettings.Object
        );
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task DonneRequeteNull_QuandInscription_AlorsBadRequest()
    {
        // Agir
        var reponse = await _comptesController.Inscription(null);

        // Affirmer
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<BadRequestResult>(reponse);
    }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ComptesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly APISettings _aPISettings;

        public ComptesController(
                SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
                UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
                IOptions<APISettings> options
            )
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _aPISettings = options.Value;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Inscription([FromBody] InscriptionRequeteDto inscription)
        {
            if (inscription == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(Constantes.Role_Administrateur))
            {
                await Initialisation();
            }

            var utilisateur = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = inscription.AdresseCourriel,
                Email = inscription.AdresseCourriel,
                Name = inscription.Nom,
                PhoneNumber = inscription.NumeroTelephone,
                EmailConfirmed = true
            };

            var resultat = await _userManager.CreateAsync(utilisateur, inscription.MotDePasse);

            if (!resultat.Succeeded)
            {
                return BadRequest(new InscriptionReponseDto
                {
                    InscriptionReussie = false,
                    Erreurs = resultat.Errors.Select(u=>u.Description)
                });
            }

            var resultatRole = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(utilisateur, Constantes.Role_Utilisateur);

            if (!resultatRole.Succeeded)
            {
                return BadRequest(new InscriptionReponseDto
                {
                    InscriptionReussie = false,
                    Erreurs = resultatRole.Errors.Select(u => u.Description)
                });
            }

            return StatusCode(201);
        }
...}
```

Here are my mocked classes:

```
public class MockRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public MockRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole> store, IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<IdentityRole>> roleValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, ILogger<RoleManager<IdentityRole>> logger)
        : base(store, roleValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, logger)
    {
    }

    public static MockRoleManager Create()
    {
        var roleStore = new Mock<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>>().Object;
        var roleValidators = new List<IRoleValidator<IdentityRole>>();
        var keyNormalizer = new UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer();
        var errors = new IdentityErrorDescriber();
        var logger = new Mock<ILogger<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>>().Object;

        return new MockRoleManager(roleStore, roleValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, logger);
    }
}

public class MockSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MockSignInManager(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
    {
    }

    public override Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
    {
        // Implement your custom behavior or return a predefined result
        return Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success);
    }
}

public class MockUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MockUserManager()
    : base(new MockUserStore(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
    {
    }
}

public class MockUserStore : IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public Task AddToRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

etc...

When I try my test, I get this error:

System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1..ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1<!0>, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1<!0>, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions>, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1<!0>>, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider)'.

**Arborescence des appels de procédure: 
MockSignInManager.ctor(UserManager`1 userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1 claimsFactory, IOptions`1 optionsAccessor, ILogger`1 logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
ComptesControllerTest.SetUp() ligne 25**

Do you know what should I do in order to be able to make the test pass?

Comment: Pls add CompetesController code

Comment: Done @BasilKosovan

Comment: Also pls add all call stack, you provided it partially.

Comment: Is there a reason why you create classes that start with Mock...(MockSignInManager, MockRoleManager) instead of using the Mock package?

Comment: I think that I cannot mock SignInManager and UserMAnager directly, so it is why I create other classes

Comment: @BasilKosovan done for the stack trace

Comment: From what I see SignInManager has only one constructor with 7 params but you pass only 6. Maybe you have different versions of Microsft.AspNetCore.Identity for your test project and your API project